# Google Maps API - How to get map type constant name (G_NORMAL_MAP, G_SATELLITE_MAP...)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I would like to get current map type constant name (G_NORMAL_MAP, G_SATELLITE_MAP...) for later use.

getCurrentMapType() returns GMapType class. Here I can call getName() method, but it returns only button label, that varies according to language.

Is it possible to get constant name? I would like to store it and later use for setting map type. If not, how do you store and later set map type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check for:

```
map.getCurrentMapType() == G_NORMAL_MAP
```

etc.